# Are recent emoji on Samsung Keyboard my own or from group chats?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

Are the recent emojis on my Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge keyboard my own recent ones, or from people using them in group chats, like Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp Messenger?

Answer (score 1):

The recent emoji tab on the Samsung keyboard, display the most recent emojis that you've used with the keyboard. You can test it simply by selecting a new emoji, and you'll see it appear in the recent tab.

In the screenshot, you can see I'm in the recent tab, and it displays the emojis I've selected in the other tabs.

[image]

Comment: So its can only be what I've used? Emojis sent to me through group chat don't show in my recent?

Comment: That's correct. Any emoji that you clicked on, even if you didn't send, will show in recent. Nothing else

Answer (score -1):

This was submitted over 4 yr's ago, and Samsung would have upgraded their phone use with emoji's, but none of the Samsungs I have "Glaxy A21; S21" ever had anything called a "Recent emoji Keyboard", they also did not show the most recent emoji's used when I clicked to place an emoji in a text message.

This article is incorrect.

Comment: The question is about an S7, not an S21, so it cannot be described as incorrect.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. The keyboard is not called "Recent emoji Keyboard" but "Samsung Keyboard". I just checked on Samsung Galaxy M12, Android 12, and Samsung Keyboard still has "recent emoji" on their emoji section.